# LE Connection CTE Request Enable unclear when CTE_Request_Interval is set to non-zero

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, specifications

This question rises from the Madrid r13 spec regarding the "LE Connection CTE Request Enable" command.

Some background about CTE_Request_Interval:
When CTE_Request_Interval is configured, a Controller which has an active "LE Connection CTE Request Enable" will transmit a LL_CTE_REQ every X Connection Intervals (which will be answered by a LL_CTE_RSP containing a CTE).

What I am trying to understand is: When is a "LE Connection CTE Request Enable" command still active.

From the spec:
"A request is active on a connection from when the Host issues a successful
command with Enable set to 0x01 until the single procedure has been
performed, the period specified by CTE_Request_Interval has ended, or a
command with Enable set to 0x00 has succeeded, whichever happens first".

From what I understand, a command ends when either:

- CTE_Request_Interval is not set, which means that LL_CTE_REQ will be transmitted and answered only once by a LL_CTE_RSP and the request will not be active any longer
- The host has disabled CTE (doesn't matter if CTE_Request_Interval was active as all other params are ignored when enable is set to 0)
- **Now the third case is what I'm having trouble with. The spec says:
  "the period specified by CTE_Request_Interval has ended"**

What does this mean?

- From what I figure, CTE_Request_Interval happens periodically, so why would the request stop being active?
- Maybe the spec means that the request is no longer active until the next period? Does this make any difference from an implementation perspective, or is it just semantics?

Thanks,
Maxim